# How to extract array which key primary_email value 1 in whole array in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
[Country] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [nicename] => Indonesia
                    [LeadCountry] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [first_name] => vikas
                            [city] => Chandigarh
                            [primary_email] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [nicename] => Indonesia
                    [LeadCountry] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [first_name] => aastha
                            [primary_email] => 1
                        )

                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [nicename] => India
                    [LeadCountry] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [first_name] => kuku
                            [primary_email] => 0
                        )

                )   

        )
```

i want to get only that part -

```
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [nicename] => Indonesia
                    [LeadCountry] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [first_name] => aastha
                            [primary_email] => 1
                        )

                )
```

Comment: 1) use a loop 2) check each sub-array for matching stuff 3) return data when found 4) ??? 5) profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array_key = false;
foreach($array['country'] as $key=>$value){
    if($value['leadCountry']['primary_email']==1){
        $array_key = $key; 
        break;
    }
}
if($array_key)
    var_dump($array['country'][$array_key];
```